# How to XPath for nodes inside a div with no attribute

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'd like to step through the `sibX` nodes to get to the labels. Strangely, I could get labels `child0x` under `sib0` but not the succeeding sib's.

I tried doing `preceding-sibling::` and `ancestor::` from `sib0` but XPath is always returning empty.

```xml
<div class="parent">
    <div> <!-- *** empty div starts here *** -->
        <div class="sib0">
            <label class="child00">child00</label>
            …
            <label class="child0N">child0N</label>
        </div>
        <div class="sib1">
            <label class="child10">child10</label>
            …
            <label class="child1N">child1N</label>
        </div>
        <div class="sib2">
            <label class="child20">child20</label>
            …
            <label class="child2N">child2N</label>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- *** empty div ends *** -->
<div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring("""<div class="parent">
    <div> 
        <div class="sib0">
            <label class="child00">child00</label>
            <label class="child0N">child0N</label>
        </div>
        <div class="sib1">
            <label class="child10">child10</label>
            <label class="child1">child1N</label>
        </div>
        <div class="sib2">
            <label class="child20">child20</label>
            <label class="child2N">child2N</label>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>""")

for e in root.xpath('/div[@class="parent"]/div/div'):
    print(e.attrib['class'])
    children = e.getchildren()
    for child in children:
        print(child.text)
```

It will output

```
sib0
child00
child0N
sib1
child10
child1N
sib2
child20
child2N
```

So you can play around with the label children for each sib div separately in the loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use contains in your XPath to reach all nodes their class contains `'sib'` in it.

```
response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "sib")]//text()').getall()
```

Also you can do same thing with `'child'`:

```
response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "child")]/text()').getall()
```